# anyone here works hard

Tags: quantifiers, any

a. Anyone here works hard to make a living.

b. Anyone here uses his brains to make a living.

c. Anyone here makes a living by using their intelligence.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct and meaningful?

I use 'everyone; and not 'anyone'. I don't see a reason why 'anyone' would be wrong, but the sentences do sound a bit strange to me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Anyone* means 'any one person', so your sentences don't make sense if you mean *everyone.*

You could say "Anyone who wants to work here must be prepared to work hard" (and similar adaptations of the other sentences).

Answer (score 1):

Anyone here = Any one person here = one person here who could be anybody

> Anyone here works hard to make a living.
>
> Any one person here works hard to make a living.
>
> One person here (who could be "any person"/"anybody" here) works hard
> to make a living.
>
> All the people here except this person (any one person) do not work
> hard to make a living.

Therefore you cannot use "Anyone here works hard to make a living." to mean "Everyone here works hard to make a living."

Furthermore "Anyone here works hard to make a living." would be a poorly constructed sentence to mean "A single individual here works hard to make a living."

Better to use "One person here works hard to make a living." to mean "A single individual here works hard to make a living."

Edit:

I thought a little more on the question "Can *anyone* be used interchangeably with *everyone*?". I suppose anyone and everyone can be used in this way if the sentence is about ability (but not actual action, in a way a hypothetical situation).

> Anyone here can work hard to make a living.
>
> Everyone here can work hard to make a living.